# Table seems to be hidden in MySQL DB, query runs fine

Tags: linux, mysql

I have a sql query done by someone.  I cannot seem to see the table where query is reading from, but offline, the table is in the same db. The dbconfig is the same offline and online.

Is there any way I can find where the table is, or unhide if hidden.

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities here, it might be worth posting your SQL query to help diagnose.  The options I can immediately think of are:

- Your "table" is actually a view which isn't showing up if you're not asking for the right things and/or aren't transferring views between the databases correctly.
- Your table is prefixed #sql and your version of MySQL is below 5.1.12 on the database server where the table is hidden.
- You aren't transferring your 'hidden' table between the databases or are somehow looking at the wrong database.
- A query may be creating a temporary table which isn't getting created correctly on the version of the database where you can't find it.

Comment: And the solution to get to see the table?